# Android - Place oposite views in a Layout

Tags: android, user-interface, layout-gravity

I have a `Horizontal Layout` and I have some views inside it. I want some to start from the left and others to start in the right, but I can't manage to do it. I tried several `Gravity` configurations but they don't do anything.

That's the case I have:

[image]

I want the Flag to be in the right and the Time to be in the left, as pointed by the arrows. I will add some more flags later.

Could anyone help me out with this? Thanks :D

EDIT:

XML so far:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/hlTopBar"
        android:background="#e6262626"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/default_time_date_string"
            android:id="@+id/tvTime"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="left" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ibUSA"
            android:src="@drawable/united_states_flag"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post ur xml then we can suggest u better. i think u need to use relative layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:layout_gravity` works in the direction opposite the orientation of the LinearLayout – the children of a `vertical LinearLayout` can use android:layout_gravity to control their positioning `horizontally (left or right)`, but not vertically. In the same way children of `horizontal LinearLayout` can use android:layout_gravity to control their positioning `vertically (top or bottom)` but not horizontally. As you are using `Horizontal LinearLayout` you can use `android:layout_gravity` to position children either `top or bottom`.For your purpose it is better to go with `RelativeLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TextView
        .........
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        .......
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a horizontal layout use a Relative layout

**example:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Time" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I will do it...but anyway to accomplish it with a linear? Just as a curiosity

Comment: @mFeinstein but you said youre gonna add more flags. if yes then its no possible in linear

Comment: I thought I could set the gravity of the text to the left and all the flags gravity to the right, so they will all go to the right leaving the middle empty....but I cant get it done

Comment: @mFeinstein yes you can do that, but the next problem is adding a new flag.

Comment: But shouldt them all go to the right in order? Ohh I guess they will be just on top of each one right?

Comment: @mFeinstein actually layout_gravity wont work for LinearLayout.. so you cant place your flag to the right without using relative layout

Answer (score 1):

The RelativeLayout is a good answer. If, however, you REALLY want to do it with a LinearLayout, try putting an empty TextView in the middle, with width=0 and weight=1.

This empty view will automatically try to fill up however much space isn't taken up by the other views.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/hlTopBar"
        android:background="#e6262626"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/default_time_date_string"
            android:id="@+id/tvTime"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spacer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ibUSA"
            android:src="@drawable/united_states_flag"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the trick, I am using the Relative Layout, but it's always nice to learn new stuff